# HP pavillion dv5400

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, virus

If my computer has been infected is it possiable for the virus to partition itself in to the recovery as well as the hp tools, therefore remaining even after system recovery?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes. Given proper security rights, malicious code could potential write additional code to a separate partition on your HDD. This question may receive more attention at https://security.stackexchange.com/.